# How to mock BulkImportResponse

Tags: moq, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert

I have a method that makes a call to Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.BulkImport to insert batch of documents. I am writing unit tests for this method. I tried mocking the BulkImport method using Moq but I am not able to create a mocked version of BulkImportResponse. Moq is not able to create mock as BulkImportResponse is a sealed class and also all the properties of this class are read only and hence I am not able to set the properties as per my requirement while mocking. Can someone suggest me how to resolve this issue?

I have below logic written in my method to test,

```
BulkImportResponse response = await bulkExecutorWrapper.BulkImport(documents, enableUpsert);
if (response .NumberOfDocumentsImported != documents.Count)
{
   //Do some  logic 
}
```

And in unit test I am trying to mock like this,

```
bulkExecutorWrapper.Setup(bulkExecutorWrapper=> bulkExecutorWrapper.BulkImport(It.IsAny<List<object>>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).ReturnsAsync(new BulkImportResponse(){NumberOfDocumentsImported = 0});
```

Comment: There is no way to mock the properties of the `BulkImportResponse` as they are `readonly`... and the `class` itself is `sealed` as you already noticed.

Comment: is there any way I can write unit tests for the same?

Comment: Not with this approach. You could wrap `bulkExecutorWrapper` with your custom interface and return some kind of a wrapper around response in order to test it...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution for setting internal or private properties. Solution I used is the one you can find on https://wrightfully.com/mocking-objects-with-restricted-access-members. Setting the read-only property is possible with reflection.

Solution is fairly easy

### Create a MockingHelper static class with following code

```
public static void SetPropertyValue(object target, string memberName, object newValue)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = GetPropertyReference(target.GetType(), memberName);
    prop.SetValue(target, newValue, null);
}

private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyReference(Type targetType, string memberName)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo = targetType.GetProperty(memberName,
                                          BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (propInfo == null && targetType.BaseType != null)
    {
        return GetPropertyReference(targetType.BaseType, memberName);
    }
    return propInfo;
}

public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)property;
    var memberExpression = lambdaExpression.Body as MemberExpression ?? 
        ((UnaryExpression)lambdaExpression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;         
    return memberExpression.Member.Name;       
}
```

This code contains some helper methods so your own code is kept clean.

### 2. Edit your test code like this

```
var response = new BulkImportResponse();
var numberOfDocumentsImportedName = MockingHelper.GetPropertyName(() => response.NumberOfDocumentsImported);
MockingHelper.SetPropertyValue(response, numberOfDocumentsImportedName, 2);

BulkExecutorMock = new Mock<IBulkExecutor>();
BulkExecutorMock
    .Setup(x => x.BulkImportAsync(It.IsAny<List<TimeSeries>>(), true, true, null, null, CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(response);
```

On line 3 you can put in any number you want that needs to be returned in the BulkImportReponse object. On the last line you then connect (as usual) the object to mocked call.

Here is my own code I needed to unit test. When I debug, the bulkImportResponse.NumberOfDocumentsImported value is 2 (as it has been set in the unit test setup)

```
BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse;
do
{
    bulkImportResponse = await _bulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync(batch, true);
} while (bulkImportResponse.NumberOfDocumentsImported < batch.Count);
```

In my code examples I used the BulkImportAsync() instead of BulkImport() but result should be the same.

Hope this helps!